# OnClick calls a function once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props

I have a button that is expected to call a function onClick.
The function is being passed in as a prop.
And this is what it looks like:

```
onClick={() => handleError && handleError()}
```

The problem here is that when I click on it, it only gets called once and doesn't get called again after that.

This is the handleError function, but the problem isn't the content of the function. It is that the function isn't being called at all after it has been called once:

```
  const handleError = (nextBtn: BtnItem) => {
    if (title === '') {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      if (nextBtn?.onClick) {
        nextBtn.onClick();
        console.log('clicked too');
      } else if (nextBtn?.route) {
        history.push(nextBtn.route);
        console.log('clicked');
      }
    }
  };
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: might it need braces? `onClick={() => { handleError && handleError() }}`

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed None

Comment: @tbjgolden Still didn't work

Comment: is the handleError prop supposed to change? why would it ever be falsy?

Comment: No, it is just taking in a value and passing it into the conditional statement I have in it @tbjgolden

Comment: What happens if you have just `onClick={() => handleError()}`

Comment: So the way it is set up, handleError is being passed in as a prop and can sometimes be undefined. So if we write it without the statement, it'll throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick={handleError ? () => handleError() : () => {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats `handleError`?
We need a bit more code to work with.

If you only want to execute the function if a variable is true. You can check it directly in the method you call and not in the onClick() itself.

Just do `onClick={handleError}`

Comment: Thanks, why exactly do you have `handleError &&` though?

Comment: Because handleError is being passed in as a prop and can possibly be undefined. So that handles that use case.

Comment: why should the function be undefined, remove the `handleError &&` and see if it works without.